# Run selenium scripts using jenkins installed in server

Tags: java, selenium, testing, jenkins, automation

I already created a selenium script and I am able make it work. Also I tried to run this using jenkins installed in my local machine. Everything works fine. It was able launch my browser and everything. But when I try using jenkins installed in linux server ang access it through my machine I cant make it work. It got an error because it cant locate my chromedriver.

I'm only using this code to launch my browser. It works in my local machine even I remove the `System.setProperty` line.

```
String driverPath = "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void launchBrowser(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Can someone help me how to make it work. A step by step procedure would be very much help.

My local machine is on windows 7 and jenkins is installed in linux server.

Comment: So you're expecting your Jenkins installation that is running on Linux to launch a Windows executable? How will that ever work?

Comment: Oh okay. But when I removed System.setProperty it still works on local machine. I read something about jenkins is capable of headless execution or remote. Should I be using that instead?

Comment: I hope there is a way to trigger my browser through my setup. Some tweaks on the code or plugins or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are hard coding the driver path:

```
String driverPath = "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe";
```

So when you execute the script through Jenkins, the system tries to find the chrome driver in Jenkins machine. You should write generalized code.
You can do that by:

```
 String chromeDriver ="src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe";

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);
```

and check-in the latest drivers in the test Project only

Comment: So I should code my selenium for linux platform since jenkins is installed in linux server? I tried your code an it says "The driver is not executable". Maybe I should read things on how make my code run in linux.

Comment: I think I'm trying to do is run my chromedriver or chrome in local machince which is in windows and not the one in linux. is this possible?